# IDE for Symfony (PHP) which is able to manage Vagrant VM's over SSH

Tags: 14.04, ssh, php, ide, vagrant

I just switched from Windows to Ubuntu on my dev Laptop. Now I'm wondering, what's the best IDE to use on Ubuntu when working with PHP?
I know there are a lot of threads here about exactly that thing, but I wasn't able to find on that brings in Vagrant.

I'm using VM's of the web servers on my dev machine for local development and they are powered by Vagrant. You can easily open an SSH connection to that VM by typing `vagrant ssh` in the CLI. I'm wondering now, is there an IDE that comes with an built in console, which is able to manage Vagrant? (On windows I used Aptana, which had an built in console, but which wasn't able to manage the SSH stuff to Vagrant, which was annoying and I wasn't able to get TWIG support up, which was even worse).

Tanks (:

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion [PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) (proprietary software) with the [Symfony2 plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7219?pr=phpStorm) is the best PHP IDE.

In every machine I use [this free course](https://www.udemy.com/installing-symfony2/?dtcode=WArY1hI267AG) which It tells you how to install everything in every OS (including [CodeSniffer](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer) with [Symfony2 Standards](https://github.com/ludofleury/symfony-coding-standard))

In PhpStorm you have a SSH client since version 7 in Tools > Start SSH session and it has TWIG support.

If you don't want to use nonfree software you can try with [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/) for example which It has [twig support with a plguin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/faces/PluginDetailPage.jsp?pluginid=37069) and Symfony2 by default